# Getting 500 response with Erlang Cowboy app

Tags: erlang, cowboy, rebar3

I'm having trouble deciphering this error message that I'm getting when hitting a simple endpoint created with Cowboy. I created a simple app with cowboy (https://github.com/overture8/cow_app) then started the app using `rebar3 shell` (not sure if this is correct?). Anyway, I'm getting this error when hitting the endpoint:

```
    Error in process <0.232.0> with exit value:
    {[{reason,undef},
      {mfa,{hello_handler,init,3}},
      {stacktrace,
          [{hello_handler,init,
               [{tcp,http},
                {http_req,#Port<0.7138>,ranch_tcp,keepalive,<0.232.0>,<<"GET">>,
                    'HTTP/1.1',
                    {{127,0,0,1},49651},
                    <<"127.0.0.1">>,undefined,8010,<<"/">>,undefined,<<>>,
                    undefined,[],
                    [{<<"host">>,<<"127.0.0.1:8010">>},
                     {<<"connection">>,<<"keep-alive">>},
                     {<<"cache-control">>,<<"max-age=0">>},
                     {<<"upgrade-insecure-requests">>,<<"1">>},
                     {<<"user-agent">>,
                      <<"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36">>},
                     {<<"accept">>,
                      <<"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8">>},
                     {<<"dnt">>,<<"1">>},
                     {<<"accept-encoding">>,<<"gzip, deflate, sdch">>},
                     {<<"accept-language">>,
                      <<"en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4">>}],
                    [{<<"connection">>,[<<"keep-alive">>]}],
                    undefined,[],waiting,<<>>,undefined,false,waiting,[],<<>>,
                    undefined},
                []],
               []},
                .
                .
                .
```

Maybe I'm just doing something completely wrong - this is my first experience with using Erlang.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I'm using a Mac and installed Erlang using `brew install erlang`. The version I have installed is "Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rebar.lock` is out of sync with `rebar.config` and is pointing to version 1.0.1 of cowboy which requires `init/3` to be exported, not `init/2`, which is what the error `... {reason,undef}, {mfa,{hello_handler,init,3}}, ...` means.

To fix, run `rebar3 upgrade cowboy` and then run `rebar3 shell`. After I run that, the application works fine for me:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8010/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: Cowboy
date: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 09:57:22 GMT
content-length: 13
content-type: text/plain

Hello Erlang!
```

Comment: Thanks so much for looking at that! Working now.